# appengine create a new user

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this basic usermodel:

```
class Song(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    lyrics = db.TextProperty()
    singer = db.StringProperty()

class UserProfile(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    song = db.ReferenceProperty(Song)
```

The google appengine api gives me the current user:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
```

The login/logout urls can be composed using:

```
users.create_login_url("/"))
```

How do i make sure if the user is registered to my app, if he is registered then fetch data corresponding to him, if he is not register create a new user object. 
Which would provide him the functionality to create/edit songs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if user:
  # user is logged in, see if a profile exists ...
  profile = UserProfile.gql('WHERE user = :1', user).get()
  if not profile:
    # no profile exists - create it
    profile = UserProfile(user=user)
    profile.put()
  # do something with profile
else:
  # rediect to login
  self.redirect(users.create_login_url("/")))
```